# How to connect Spartacus with a custom API

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have a custom API in the backend. There's no backend component for this. I need to call directly on the API. My question is I need to display the data inside a certain page slot. is this possible in spartacus? Please advise :)

Comment: Is your 'custom API' in any way related to SAP Commerce Cloud? or do you want to connect Spartacus with a non-CommerceCloud backend?
or will Spartacus work with SAP Commerce Cloud backend normally, but only one feature (special new component) relies on this custom API?

Comment: yes, for example, I have a news section on the homepage. There's a custom API for news to load the data. I need to put it in a certain slot in homepage.

Comment: I think I solved the problem. I just need to add CMSFlexComponent placeholder since CmsComponent can accept typeCode or FlexType


cmsComponents: {
    <item type | flex type>: {
        component: <Angular Component>,
    },
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just need to create a CMSFlexComponent for a placeholder since cmsComponents can accept also a flex type:

```
cmsComponents: {
    <item type | flex type>: {
        component: <Angular Component>,
    },
}
```